# PHP base64_encode not working in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, function

I am trying to add the following code work in a php file but it is not working when i use base64_encode of php...

```
alert('print-generalbill.php?a=r&i='+<?php echo base64_encode($InvID); ?>);
```

But it works fine when i use the code without base64_encode

```
alert('print-generalbill.php?a=r&i='+<?php echo $InvID; ?>);
```

What should be the solution to this?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What's the result and what do you expect instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do this. Its a matter of actually quoting the string. Base 64 strings contain valid javascript operators such as `=`.

```
<?php
$value = 'print-generalbill.php?a=r&i=' . base64_encode($InvID);
?>
alert('<?php echo $value; ?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
alert('print-generalbill.php?a=r&i='+<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode($InvID)); ?>);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" or "didn't solve" is not a programmer definition. Please be specific